# Form validation bootstrap is not working on modal form with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to validate a modal form which I post with ajax. This is the code i am using. The problem is that it dont show any errors in console.

```
$('#addRecordForm')
    .formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            truckNumber: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The truckNumber is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            provider: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .on('success.form.fv', function (e) {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(e.target),
            fv = $form.data('formValidation');

        // Use Ajax to submit form data
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/tallys/check-record",
            data: {
                rowCount: rowCount,
                truckNumber: $("#truckNumber").val(),
                provider: $("#provider").val(),
                netAmount: $("#netAmount").val(),
                moisture: $("#moisture").val(),
                impurities: $("#impurities").val(),
                broken: $("#broken").val(),
                damaged: $("#damaged").val()
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success == 1) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                } else if (result.success == 0) {}
            }
        });
    });
```

This code runs when i click button with id add_record. I didnt paste it but its there and it works. Do you see something wrong with the code ?

UPDATE: I found where the problem is. The button should be placed in the form section and in my case it wasnt. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: bootply link please?

Comment: The question is how to trigger .formValidation from button who is not in the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to submit your form using a button outside the form. to do this you will need to specify the form you are submitting since the button is out of the form.

```
<form id="the form">...your code in here..</form>
<input type="submit" form="theform" />
```

Since this doesn't work in IE :D you can use JQuery to do so

```
<form id="the form">...your code in here..</form>
<button type="button" id="theSubmit">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#theSubmit").click(function() {
           $("#theForm").submit();
       });
    });
</script>
```